# Custom tailored leave-one out cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have around 1000 data points and each data point belongs to a specific user. In total I have 80 users, so each user has around 12 data points. I can do leave one user out cross-validation by using `LeaveOneGroupOut` from scikit-learn.

But now I would like to use leave-one-out cross-validation, i.e. using only one data point in the test set (instead of a user). But instead of using the full remaining training set, I would like to use a slightly different training set: If data point n from user x is in the test set, then the training set should consist of the data points of all other users plus data points 1,2,...n-1 of user x. If data point 1 from user x is in the test set, then no data point from this user is in the training set.

How can this be done? I'm using a `Pipeline` with `RandomizedSearchCV` and SVM, so I would be very happy if there is a solution like `LeaveOneGroupOut` which I can pass to these methods.